# How to send reminders to others on specific dates each year

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I need to send people reminders on different dates each year.

How do I do this in Outlook?

Should I create a task and share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create and assign task(s) or create calendar appointment(s) with attendees.

Comment: thank you, I create some tasks and shared them. I wish Outlook had an easier way, something dedicated to this